# How to reduce CPU and RAM consumption of Word proofing (spell checking)?

Tags: microsoft-word

The past few days, I've noticed an issue where Microsoft Word was hogging a lot of the CPU, which didn't seem to happen before or maybe I've just missed until now. It only happened with one particularly long document, and eventually after some methodical analysis, I narrowed the problem down to be the spell-checker.

What happens if that when I open the document initially, CPU usage by Word is **very** high (sometimes over 25% on an Intel Core i7) for quite some time. Memory usage is also significantly increased.

What I noticed is that as soon as spell-checking stops scanning the whole document, CPU and RAM usage drops to basically nothing, even if I continue editing the document.

I tested with Word 2010 on Windows 7 and Word 2019 on Windows 10. Both have this issue, although Word 2010 on Windows 7 seems to be more efficient, putting slightly less load on the CPU and finishing noticeably faster with the "initial check". My guess is that the newer versions of Word do additional extra unnecessary stuff.

Here it is from Word 2019:

[image]

[image]

As soon as the X comes on, indicating that it's no longer checking, CPU usage drops to normal.

It's helpful to know that this is the issue, but I don't really want to disable spell-check, especially not for this document (spell-checking is very much a must-have).

I don't use the spell-checking tool to proof the entire document - except very rarely when I manually go through parts of it. Most of the time, I only use the real-time aspect of it to catch mistakes as they are made.
Would it be possible to do any of the following?

- Somehow "cache" the results of the initial check so it doesn't need to be repeated *every* time I open the document? (probably not possible)
- Disable the "initial" check but continue spell checking everything I write after I open the document? (seems like it could be possible, though I haven't found out how to do this without disabling it entirely)
- Instead of checking the whole document... maybe just check the last XX pages?

If not, it seems I should just leave it open all the time and never close out of it, but I'm wondering if there's another way. This is really starting to create problems. Sometimes the "initial check" can go on for 10-15 minutes or more.

**UPDATE:**

I did another test with some VMs on a computer with 8 CPU cores:

I tested with Office 2019 on the host (Windows 10) and on Office 2010 in VMs running Windows 7 x64, Windows Vista x64, and Windows XP SP3 x32.

I noticed that in Windows 7, I encountered similar problems, but Windows Vista and Windows XP did not seem to share the issue.

I looked into the VM settings and saw that Windows 7 was set to use 4 of the 8 CPU cores, while Windows Vista and XP were only allowed to use 1. When I changed Windows 7 to use just 1 CPU core, and reduced the amount of RAM allocated to it, the problem disappeared there as well.

Thus, "CPU throttling" seems to be one way of dealing with it. If you have the luxury of running Word in a VM, and you have multiple CPU cores and just let the VM use one of them, it will use 100% of the CPU in that VM, but it won't bottleneck the system and make the fans come on. Hardly ideal but it does make it less annoying.